# Are subanalytic sets measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, logic, lebesgue-measure

Definition. Let $M$ be a real analytic manifold and $X\subset M$ be a subset. $X$ is called semianalytic if it can be described by analytic equalities and inequalities (ie $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^p\bigcap_{j=1}^q X_{ij}$ where $X_{ij}=\{x\in X \mid f_{ij}>0\}$ or $X_{ij}=\{x\in X \mid f_{ij}=0\}$ for real-analytic functions $f_{ij}$ on $M$.

Definition. Let $M$ be a real analytic manifold and $E\subset M$ be a subset. $E$ is said to be subanalytic if there exists for each $e\in E$ an open neighborhood $U\subset M$ such that $E\cap U$ is the projection of a relatively compact semianalytic set (ie there exists a real analytic manifold $N$ and relatively compact semianalytic subset $A\subset M\times N$ such that $E\cap U =\pi(A)$ where $\pi:M\times N\to M$ is the projection).

Question: Suppose $M$ is a real-analytic manifold and $E\subset M$ is a subanalytic set. Is $E$ measurable?

I suspect the answer is yes, but I'm far removed from my measure-theory classes and I'm getting tripped up in dealing with the interaction between the projection involved in the definition of $E$ and how measurability works with projections.

Most of the references I've been reading about subanalytic sets (Bierstone/Milman, Denkowska, etc) don't talk about whether they are measurable, so I'm not sure whether this is easy and I should be kicking myself or whether it's moderately difficult and I found an interesting question to ask.

Non-question: If someone knows a good MSE tag to deal with subanalytic sets, please suggest it in the comments or edit this post to add it. subanalytic-sets doesn't exist, definable-sets doesn't exist, o-minimal-sets doesn't exist, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the interest of not leaving questions unanswered around on MSE, the claim is true - subanalytic sets are measurable, and the proof is essentially the cell decomposition theorem. See https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/polyens/OMIN.pdf for a reference. Some care should be taken since subanalytic sets do not form an o-minimal structure, but bounded subanalytic sets do, so one may subdivide $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a countable collection of bounded cubes, run the proof on each cube, and then conclude the general case.