# Are semianalytic sets Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, analytic-geometry, analyticity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be an analytic function, and consider the semianalytic set $E:=\{\vec x\in\mathbb{R}^n|f(\vec x)=0\}$. Is the set $E$ automatically Lebesgue measurable?

**Note:** My question is possibly related to [Are subanalytic sets measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370632/are-subanalytic-sets-measurable) but I get lost in the definition of subanalytic, so it would really help me out if someone could walk me through if/why measurability works for this simpler class of sets. If this is related to a known (named) theorem, I'd be more than happy to just understand the connection to that result, no need to prove the whole theorem.

Comment: Semianalytic sets are automatically subanalytic (subanalytic means locally expressable as the projection of a semianalytic set), so the linked post applies. I can go in to more detail in an answer if you'd like - if so, please mention any specific points you'd like me to touch on.

Comment: I assume (since you mention "subanalytic") that you mean "analytic" in the usual sense of analysis, i.e., locally given by convergent power series. If that's correct, then, since analytic functions are continuous, your set $E$ will be closed, and therefore Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Semianalytic means lying in the boolean algebra of sets generated by inequalities $f>0$ and equalities $g=0$ for $f,g$ real-analytic functions, so your claim is very close to correct (and a good deal simpler than my initial comment - +1).

Comment: @KReiser The question is about the set $\{\vec x\in\mathbb R^n\,|\,f(\vec x)=0\}$ for an analytic $f$, which is a lot simpler than merely semianalytic. I was only answering that easy question. But you're right that the general semianalytic case is almost equally easy.

Comment: @AndreasBlass ah, good catch - I didn't see the special case.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for those explanations. I completely forgot that all closed sets are measurable (it's been a while since I've done any measure theory!). If you want to type that up as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @KReiser My question is related to the more specific problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969161/can-n1-distinct-positive-vectors-in-mathbbrn-0-agree-on-n-distinct . I believe I can answer that question by using this, but it would be really helpful to have someone with more measure theory background double check. I will type up an answer tomorrow, would you mind looking at it later in the day to see if it makes sense? (I don't think I can tag you directly in another question.) That would be super helpful!!

Comment: @KReiser I have typed up how I believe this is relevant to the question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969161/can-n1-distinct-positive-vectors-in-mathbbrn-0-agree-on-n-distinct. It would be awesome if you could give it a quick look-over!!